# Series of animations in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i show a series of Animations in flutter, I have a class called `CardAnimation`
which take in 2 parameters fromIndex and toIndex. I want to call `CardAnimation` 5 times with fromIndex being 1 for all and toIndex ranging from 2 to 6. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
else if(_animation.isDismissed){
      setState(() {
        show = false;
        if (i < 6){
          i ++;
          CardAnimation(fromIndex: 1, toIndex: i);
        }
      
      });
    }
```

Even though its coming inside the if statement the `CardAnimation` is not working. oh and I am calling `CardAnimation` inside `CardAnimation`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at [Staggered animations](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations)