# Flutter move a container at constant speed

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I need to move container at constant speed, my code moves it to the required location but not at constant speed it moves at different speeds each time.

```
double xVal = currentXLocationOfTheContainer;
double yVal = currentYLocationOfTheContainer;

static double xDistance = requiedXLocationOfTheContainer - currentXLocationOfTheContainer;
static double yDistance = requiedXLocationOfTheContainer - currentYLocationOfTheContainer; 

Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
  setState(() {
    xVal = xVal + xDistance/100;
    yVal = yVal + yDistance/100;

  });
});
```

I need to find a constant value to add to xVal and yVal.

I have the total distance, speed and total time so how to find distance travelled in 10 milliseconds?

Comment: use `AnimationController` instead of `Timer.periodid` for cases like this

Comment: @pskink I stated by using an ```AnimationController``` but there are things I need to do which it can't do so I had to using ```Timer.periodid```

Comment: what "things" do you mean?

Comment: I shared some of those 'things' in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632464/series-of-animations-in-flutter this was where I used AnimationController but I couldn't find a way to continue but I was able to continue with ```Timer.periodic```

Comment: there is no single use of `AnimationController` in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632464/series-of-animations-in-flutter) you linked, what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I use ```AnimationController``` in that class.

Answer (score 0):

the formula is  `V = Distance/Duration` so for constant speed we need constant Distance in constant time.

for Example `2000 pixel per second` Or `2 pixel per Millisecond`

### Fist way : const distance.

---

```
double xVal = currentXLocationOfTheContainer;
double yVal = currentYLocationOfTheContainer;

static double xDistance = requiedXLocationOfTheContainer - currentXLocationOfTheContainer;
static double yDistance = requiedXLocationOfTheContainer - currentYLocationOfTheContainer; 

Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
  setState(() {
    xVal = xVal + (xDistance > 0 ? 20 : -20);
    yVal = yVal + (yDistance > 0 ? 20 : -20);

  });
});
```

note:speed in above code is `2 * sqrt(2) = 2.8284` pixel per millisecond

---

### second way : const time.

for real Distance we use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

```
import 'dart:math';

double xVal = currentXLocationOfTheContainer;
double yVal = currentYLocationOfTheContainer;

static double xDistance = requiedXLocationOfTheContainer - currentXLocationOfTheContainer;
static double yDistance = requiedXLocationOfTheContainer - currentYLocationOfTheContainer; 

var realDisatanse = sqrt((xDistance*xDistance) + (yDistance*yDistance));
var speedPerMillisecond = 2;
var time = realDisatanse / speedPerMillisecond; 

Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: time), (timer) {
  setState(() {
    xVal = xVal + xDistance;
    yVal = yVal + yDistance;

  });
});
```

note:speed in above code is `2` pixel per millisecond

Comment: Both the methods doesn't work, For the first method, adding a const distance would make the container go in a 60 degree angle every time which is not what I want and for the second method, we can actually change value of time during the process instead adding a constant distance value might work .

Answer (score 0):

You can use AnimatedPositioned widget which has default curve = Curves.linear

Animation as per documentation: https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/animation/curve_linear.mp4

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final targetX = 200;
  final targetY = 200;

  int currentX = 0;
  int currentY = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          currentX = targetX;
          currentY = targetY;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('AnimatedPositionedExample')),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedPositioned(
            child: Container(color: Colors.lime, height: 50, width: 50),
            left: currentX.toDouble(),
            top: currentY.toDouble(),
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            curve: Curves.linear,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I stated by using an ```AnimationController``` but there are things I need to do which it can't do, so I had to using the ```Timer.periodic```.